# Copying an object to another object with specific condition

Tags: javascript, object

The default object is:

```
var employee = {
    'name': 'Hermione',
    'salary': 1000
};
```

My question is, how to copy that to another object with this formatting?

```
var employee = {
    'Hermione': 1000
};
```

I've tried:

```
for (var prop in employee) {
    console.log(prop, employee[prop]); // 'name' 'Hermione'
    // what next?
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var employees = [];
employees.push({ 'name': 'name1', 'salary': 1000 });
employees.push({ 'name': 'name2', 'salary': 2000 });
employees.push({ 'name': 'name3', 'salary': 3000 });
```

What I want to achieve:

```
var employees = [
    {'name1': 1000},
    {'name2': 2000},
    {'name3': 3000}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an array of those objects?
For single object the case is rather simple:

```
var employee2 = {};
employee2[employee['name']] = employee['salary'];
```

or for modern browsers:

```
var employee2 = {
    [employee['name']]: employee['salary']
};
```

---

**update**

for array of objects:

```js
var employees = [
  { name: 'name1', salary: 1000 },
  { name: 'name2', salary: 2000 },
  { name: 'name3', salary: 3000 }
];

var employees2 = employees.map(employee => ({[employee.name]: employee.salary}));

console.dir(employees2);
```

for older browsers:

```
var employees2 = employees.map(function(employee) {
     var result = {};
     result[employee['name']] = employee['salary'];
     return result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Or [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var employees = [];
employees.push({ 'name': 'n1', 'salary': 1000 });
employees.push({ 'name': 'n2', 'salary': 2000 });
employees.push({ 'name': 'n3', 'salary': 3000 });

var reduced = employees
  .reduce((res, val) => {
    res[val.name] = val.salary;
    return res;
  }, Object.create(null))
;

console.log('reduced', reduced);

var mapped = employees
  .map(i => ({[i.name] : i.salary}))
;
console.log('mapped', mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

newobj = {}; newobj[oldObj.name] = oldObj.salary